# Unusual OO behavior?

Tags: php, oop

here is some php code:

```
class A {
  private function action(){
    echo 1;
  }
  public static function callAction(A $a){
    $a->action();
  }
}

$a = new A;
A::callAction($a);
```

can someone explain me why does object method is vissible from static method context how does following code works in other languages ???

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is here? Does this code give you errors? 
You've made a strange construction, but I think it's syntactically correct..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `private` means the function is accessible from within this *class* only, not from within this *object*. The behaviour is the same in all languages I know.

Answer (score 0):

As your $a object is passed as a parameter in A::callAction(), you can call any of its methods, static or not.

And as in A::callAction(A) you are in the implementation of A class, you can call $a->action.

Simple ? =)